# Load SwipeBox gallery from single link

Tags: jquery

I'm using Swipebox and it works fine for loading Gallery from thumbs, or Video from a single link - but how can I load a Gallery from a single link.

The Docs give us this option
http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#advanced

but I don't want the refs to images to be in the script as they need to be unlimited  / editable in the CMS etc

Any ideas?

Cheers
.ben.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps as it is not perfect solution:
Create div which holds first thumbnail or image. Below that first image list all images which belong to gallery. Assign via css properties for this div with hidden overflow: div size match your first image height and width.
As I said it is not a good solution though but at least it works.

html

```
<div class="hiddenoveflow">
<a rel="gallery-1" href="big/image1.jpg" class="swipebox">
    <img src="small/image1.jpg" alt="image">
</a>
<a rel="gallery-1" href="big/image2.jpg" class="swipebox">
    <img src="small/image2.jpg" alt="image">
</a>
</div>
```

css

```
.hiddenoverflow{height:100px;width:100px;overflow:hidden}/// match dimensions of your first small image
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I hide all but one thumbnail using CSS and of course keeping the data attribute "rel" the same across all the images in the gallery.

I use a class called "hide" and apply it to all the thumbnails I did not want to be seen. (Utilizing Bootstrap 3.3.2)

```
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

But I do not know how you are posting the images in the first place.
This was simpler for me because I am using PHP to pull images from a folder and putting them up automatically in a certain order and containers.

To give you an idea of my meaning;

```
function gal($dir,$alt){
    echo "\t\t\t\t\t",'<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">',PHP_EOL,
         "\t\t\t\t\t\t",'<div class="well well-sm text-center">',PHP_EOL,
         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", '<h4>'.$alt.'</h4>',PHP_EOL;
    $images = glob($dir."*.{jpg,JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);
    $f1 = 0; $f2 = 1;
    foreach ($images as $img){
        echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",'<a rel="'.$alt.'" class="swipebox'.($f2?' preload':'').($f1?' hide':'').'" href="'.$img.'" title="'.$alt.'">', PHP_EOL,
             "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",'<img src="thumbs.php?src='.$img.'&w=192&h=128&a=t"'.($f2?' class="img-responsive img-thumb center-block"':'').' alt="'.$alt.'"></a>',PHP_EOL;
        $f1 = 1; $f2 = 0;
    }
    echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t",'</div>',PHP_EOL,"\t\t\t\t\t",'</div>',PHP_EOL;
}
```

Glob is used to cycle through the images in a folder set using $dir, while the $f1 flag is used to apply the .hide class to all but the first image, and $f2 is a flag that sets the .preload class to only the first image.

$alt being used to title the gallery, links, and image alts while also keeping all the images to the same gallery using the rel attribute.

As you can see, I am a stickler for proper formatting.

You can also be a total HTML Demon and put only the anchors up without all but one thumbnail. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zzw7M/5/)

**EDIT**: And technically you do not even need thumbnails, I know I am a tad late but it popped into my head while I was driving.

You can stick practically anything between that first anchor and it would open the gallery as long as it followed through properly. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zzw7M/6/)

In fact, I am going to change the PHP on my site to reflect this mental breakthrough.

**UPDATE**: This is what the changed PHP looks like:

```
function galOne($dir,$alt){
    $galOne =   "\t\t\t\t\t".'<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">'.PHP_EOL.
                "\t\t\t\t\t\t".'<div class="well well-sm text-center">'.PHP_EOL.
                "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t".'<h4>'.$alt.'</h4>'.PHP_EOL;
    $images = glob($dir."*.{jpg,JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);
    $flag1 = 0; $flag2 = 1;
    foreach ($images as $img){
        $galOne .=  "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t".'<a rel="'.$alt.'" class="swipebox'.($flag2? ' preload':'').'" href="'.$img.'" title="'.$alt.'">'.($flag1? '</a>':'').PHP_EOL.
                    ($flag2? "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t".'<img src="thumbs.php?src='.$img.'&w=192&h=128&a=t" class="img-responsive img-thumb center-block" alt="'.$alt.'">'.'</a>'.PHP_EOL.'':'');
                    $flag1 = 1; $flag2 = 0;
    }
    $galOne .=  "\t\t\t\t\t\t".'</div>'.PHP_EOL."\t\t\t\t\t".'</div>'.PHP_EOL;

    return ($galOne);
    unset ($galOne, $images, $img, $flag1, $flag2);
}
```

This will output like so when fed "img/Gallery/various/" and "Various":

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
    <div class="well well-sm text-center">
        <h4>Various</h4>
        <a rel="Various" class="swipebox preload" href="img/Gallery/various/DSC04675.JPG" title="Various">
            <img src="thumbs.php?src=img/Gallery/various/DSC04675.JPG&w=192&h=128&a=t" class="img-responsive img-thumb center-block" alt="Various"></a>
        <a rel="Various" class="swipebox" href="img/Gallery/various/DSC04712.JPG" title="Various"></a>
        <a rel="Various" class="swipebox" href="img/Gallery/various/IMG_0380.JPG" title="Various"></a>
        <a rel="Various" class="swipebox" href="img/Gallery/various/IMG_0382.JPG" title="Various"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In fact, I could anchor the header with the href only being "#" and as long as the rel points to "Various" and the class sticks to "swipebox" it would load up that gallery. Although the first image would be nothing but loading gif being that the href is "#".

Don't ask me why I "unset" everything. It is just a quirk I picked up from someone else teaching me how to code. Something about memory leaks, I can't even remember why.